# symfony2 execute CREATE table query into controller

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my symfony2 application there is a need to create a table on the basis of 
user selection. if user selects yes then a new table will be create into database.

I am trying to create table query into symfony2 controller but getting error message

```
Error: Expected SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE, got 'CREATE'
```

Is it any way to run create table query into controller.

Comment: it's a very bad practice why you wanna do that in the controller you can just run this command : php app/console generate:doctrine:entity

Comment: @elkorchianas , I just update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it's BAD practice, but it just a single working way that i know.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->getConnection()->exec('create table tmp (id int)');
```